# Django Grab Apache User

Tags: python, django

Django 1.6, Python 3.3

I just want to grab the user that was authenticated by Apache and save it as a variable.  Is there a django-y way to do this?  What about just straight up in Python?

If it helps I plan to use the value as the default for a model field - but I would also like to use it in other places in my code.

Thanks.

Comment: What auth system are you using? (eg: Django's, WebAuth, Shibboleth, etc.)

Comment: If you are using Django's auth system, check out the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/ . After authenticating, you should be able to just use `request.user`.

Comment: I'm not using any auth system in Django itself.  This project, and many other things are globally protected by basic Apache HTTP authentication and I just want to be able to pluck out that user so I can use it for various things in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Apache's auth sets the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable which is accessible in a Django view.**

Specifically, as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/auth-remote-user/),

> ... in Django, REMOTE_USER is made available in the request.META attribute.

However, **you need to set up MiddleWare so Django knows to grab the `REMOTE_USER`** ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/auth-remote-user/#configuration)):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    '...',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    '...',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)
```

After that, you can use `request.META['REMOTE_USER']` to authenticate and auto-login the user.

Comment: What do I need to import to use request.META?  When I try to use that I get:

global name 'request' is not defined

Comment: Where are you trying to use this? The `request` object is made available in any Django view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a custom module I created.  I want to be able to call it wherever I need it, for example, in models.py.

Comment: You need to either pass the entire request object or grab the user from the view and pass it into your "custom module" as a parameter. Django is much more "functional" in that sense.

Comment: I can make it work in a view itself.  For example: 

def user(request):
    output = request.META['REMOTE_USER']
    return HttpResponse(output)

But I don't know how to call that outside of views.py because the function needs "request" passed to it, and I don't have request where I am calling from.

Comment: Right, from the view you then must pass the "user" object wherever you want to access it. Django has no concept of the "globally logged in user." Instead, it can grab the user when they access a view and percolate from there.

Comment: Why can't you pass the user where you need it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59431/discussion-between-casey-falk-and-user3449833).